# How to use AutoMapper with Entity Framework Database First approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper, ef-database-first

I am working on MVC 5, Entity Framework with Db First Approach. Whenever i use

```
public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string CustomerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual string City { get; set; }

    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Country(AllowCountry="USA")]
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

for Validation in Entity Framework generated class and if i update my .edmx file i lost all code that  i was written. Someone suggest me use Auto-mapper. I try to find some basic example but i didn't get. Guide me. How to start and where from? I am new in MVC, Entity Framework.

Comment: [Chris Pratt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt) has a couple of good articles [here](http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-getting-started/) that might help you get started

Comment: Add annotations to your view models rather than the generated code, use automapper to to transfer the data between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another approach to retain the validation attribute code even if you update the model. 
In the **Models** folder, add a class named **Metadata.cs** (class that contain all of the validation attributes).

```js
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YourProjectName.Models
{
    public class CustomerMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }

        
    }
}
```

Next, you must associate the model classes with the metadata classes.For that In the **Models** folder, add a class named **PartialClasses.cs**.

```js
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YourProjectName.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetadata))]
    public partial class Customer
    {
    }
}
```

[Source](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation)

Comment: While this can be acceptable, views often involve editing only a subset of the models data or will need additional properties (`SelectLists` for generating dropdowns etc) so creating a view model and mapping from the data model is generally a better approach